# This code does't run and gives no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a tabular menu. 
I have five tabs that each one has a specific div element. 
When I click on the tab, for example tab1, the div element with id tab1 get class content and other div's get their class removed but it does not seem to work

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<style type="text/css"> 
    body, html, div, ul,li,a  {margin:0; padding:0;}
    body {font-family:arial;font-size:12px;}
    .clear {clear:both;}
    a img {border:none;}
    ul {
        list-style:none;
        position:relative; 
        z-index:2;
        top:1px;
        display:table;
        border-left:1px solid #f5ab36;
        }
    ul li {float:left;}
    ul li a {
        background:#ffd89b;
        color:#222;
        display:block;
        padding:6px 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        border-right:1px solid #f5ab36;
        border-top:1px solid #f5ab36;
        border-right:1px solid #f5ab36;
        }
    ul li a.selected  
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
        color:#344385;
        background:#fff;
    }
    h1 {
            display:block;
            width:600px;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding:20px 0;
            color:#fff;
        }
    #navigation {width:602px; margin: 0 auto;}
    .content {width:600px; margin:0 auto;height:200px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #f5ab36;z-index:1;text-align:center;padding:10px 0; display:block;}
    #logo {width:600px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0; text-align:right;}
    .remove
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style> 

</head> 

<body> 
<h1>Simple tabbed menu</h1> 

<div id="navigation"> 
    <ul> 
        <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="1" class="">Tab 1</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="2">Tab 2</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="3">Tab 3</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="4">Tab 4</a></li> 
        <li><a class="selected" href="javascript:void(0);" id="5">Tab 5</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
<div id="remove1">
    <div id="tab1" class="">
     pannel doesn't always shows everythings
    </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="">
    this is not a favorit glass
     </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="">Oh my god we don't have such strong idea</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="">my favorit pannel is hear</div>
    <div id="tab5" class="">Do not talk too much</div>      
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
        $('#remove1 div').removeClass('content');   
        $('#navigation ul a').click(function(){
            $('#navigation ul a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');


            if($(this).attr('id')==1)
            {

        $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
                $('#tab1').addClass('content');

            }
            else if($(this).attr('id')==2)
            {

                $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
                $('#tab2').addClass('content');             

            }
            else if($(this).attr('id')==3)
            {

                $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
                $('#tab3').addClass('content');


            }
            else if($(this).attr('id')==4)                      
            {
                $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
                $('#remove1 div').removeClass('content');

                $('#tab4').addClass('content');

            }
            else if($(this).attr('id')==5)                      
            {

                $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
                $('#tab5').addClass('content');
            }
        });


    });
</script> 



</body></html>
```

when I click on the an element that is expected to hide all the div element and show the specific div it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please use an external stylesheet

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.net to show the issue and describe what happens and what you want to happen. Downvoters give a noob a chance!

Comment: You code is not using the power of jquery. Simply reset all siblings and select the clicked tab

Comment: You always add the class `remove`, but never remove it. An element’s class is a set; when you add something again, it doesn’t take precedence over the rest.

Comment: i think, the question is clear. i don't know why you don't understand what i am saying. i said i want to make a tabular menu. the problem is when i click on the menu the div element doesn't show. let me to give an example: when i click on the tab one it is expected to show the div with id tab1 but it doesn't do for me.

Comment: OP posted complete code (opening header tag is missing but ok). It can just be copied and pasted if you're interested in solving this.

Comment: @mplungjan there are many parts of the world where jsfiddle takes forever and then some to load and that is only if it's not completely blocked. Posting code isn't a bad idea especially if the OP doesn't know where exactly the problem is. There are questions where people post tons of unrelated code but in this case the page can be copied and pasted to re produce the problem of tab content not showing so I'm happy with it.

Comment: A question here will have a much better chance if there is a fiddle. I for one did not today feel like making one - I often do, but in this case the code base was too poor to try to fix. I spent time trying to salvage it by rewriting the actual question but that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to remove the `remove` class so it stays hidden. No need for all the if statements, one option is to add a `data-tabid` to your anchors and use that as the id to display the divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
    body, html, div, ul,li,a  {margin:0; padding:0;}
    body {font-family:arial;font-size:12px;}
    .clear {clear:both;}
    a img {border:none;}
    ul {
        list-style:none;
        position:relative; 
        z-index:2;
        top:1px;
        display:table;
        border-left:1px solid #f5ab36;
        }
    ul li {float:left;}
    ul li a {
        background:#ffd89b;
        color:#222;
        display:block;
        padding:6px 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        border-right:1px solid #f5ab36;
        border-top:1px solid #f5ab36;
        border-right:1px solid #f5ab36;
        }
    ul li a.selected  
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
        color:#344385;
        background:#fff;
    }
    h1 {
            display:block;
            width:600px;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding:20px 0;
            color:#fff;
        }
    #navigation {width:602px; margin: 0 auto;}
    .content {width:600px; margin:0 auto;height:200px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #f5ab36;z-index:1;text-align:center;padding:10px 0; display:block;}
    #logo {width:600px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0; text-align:right;}
    .remove
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style> 

</head> 

<body> 
<h1>Simple tabbed menu</h1> 

<div id="navigation"> 
    <ul> 
        <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="1" data-tabid="tab1" class="">Tab 1</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="2" data-tabid="tab2">Tab 2</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="3" data-tabid="tab3">Tab 3</a></li> 
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="4" data-tabid="tab4">Tab 4</a></li> 
        <li><a class="selected" href="javascript:void(0);" id="5" data-tabid="tab5">Tab 5</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
<div id="remove1">
    <div id="tab1" class="">
     pannel doesn't always shows everythings
    </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="">
    this is not a favorit glass
     </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="">Oh my god we don't have such strong idea</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="">my favorit pannel is hear</div>
    <div id="tab5" class="">Do not talk too much</div>      
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
        $('#remove1 div').removeClass('content');
        $("#tab5").addClass('content');
        $('#tab5').removeClass('remove');

        $('#navigation ul a').click(function () {
            var tabID = this.getAttribute("data-tabid")
                .toString();
            $('#navigation ul a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('#remove1 div').addClass('remove');
            $('#' + tabID).addClass('content');
            $('#' + tabID).removeClass('remove');
        });


    });
</script> 



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You always add the class `remove`, but never remove it. An element’s class is a set; when you add something again, it doesn’t take precedence over the rest.

You could copy and paste a couple `removeClass`es everywhere (including the one you have for #4 but seem to have forgotten everywhere else), or you could use concatenation to find the right element:

```
var $links = $('#navigation a');
var $tabs = $('#remove1 > div');

$links.click(function(e) {
    $links.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $tabs.removeClass('content').addClass('remove');
    $('#tab' + this.id).addClass('content').removeClass('remove');
});
```

Next up, make that an external stylesheet and link to it using a `<link>` element. After that, make `display: none;` the default and take out that `.addClass('remove')` and `.removeClass('remove')`. `javascript:void(0)` is really bad practice; take out the `id` attribute (which you’re misusing; it should be `data-id` if anything) and link to the actual tab:

```
<li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
```

Then stop the link from being followed at the end of your event listener:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

And use the entire `href` attribute instead of that not-so-nice concatenation:

```
$(this.getAttribute('href')).addClass('content');
```

Finally, you should totally [drop jQuery and try plain old JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/minitech/5845169), given a decent browser.